# React Component Ignoring the <h1> tag

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm very new to React and just experimenting to understand the syntax better.
When I add components to the app component it's and preview this on webpage it's ignoring the `code<h1>Hello</h1>` in the app component and only showing the Form components `code<h3>Form</h3>` header. I'm a little confused and have been trying to figure this out for some time now...

App component below.

```
import React from 'react';

import Form from './Form';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Hello</h1>,
            <Form />
    );
}

export default App;
```

Form component

```
import React from 'react';

const Form = () => {
    return (
        <h3>Form</h3>
    );
}
export default Form;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

```
return (<h1>Hello</h1>, <Form />);
```

This is a [Comma Operator expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The **comma operator** (`,`) evaluates each of its operands (from left
> to right) and returns the value of the last operand. This lets you
> create a compound expression in which multiple expressions are
> evaluated, with the compound expression's final value being the value
> of the rightmost of its member expressions.

Only the `<Form />` JSX literal is returned.

## Solution

React components should return a single node.

[Rendering multiple elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
import React from 'react';

import Form from './Form';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>,
      <Form />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Or use a fragment to not pollute the DOM

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

import Form from './Form';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>Hello</h1>,
      <Form />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew Reese. I think I read you can also use empty <> </> as well. I thought I had tried that but obviously not. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Yes, I included a link to help explain `Fragments`. `<>...</>` is [shorthand](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) for them, though some transpiler settings won't translate that back down to pure JS (works out-of-the-box with a fresh project from `create-react-app`).